# Use result from sql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have following in php code:

```
$result=mysql_query ("SELECT title, image FROM board order by date limit 15");cq();
```

I would like to replace 15 with result from sql query:

```
SELECT count FROM cat_count
```

So I put to php but it doesn't work:

```
$cat_count=mysql_query ("SELECT count FROM cat_count");cq();
$result=mysql_query ("SELECT title, image FROM board order by date limit ".$cat_count."");cq();
```

Thanks

Comment: mysql_query  has been deprecated , use mysqli_query. Also try to use prepared statments. In your code you are not catching the results of the query by using mysqli_fetch_array() function. Also where your connection in the query?  I would suggest you to take proper PHP MySQL tutorials.

Comment: for connection we reference to different file

Comment: @Prabhjot Singh Kainth : how the final query would look like with mysqli_fetch_array() ?

Comment: kindly follow the basic tutorials , you are missing basic concepts.

Comment: while($cat_count = mysql_fetch_array($cat_count)) {
 echo "".$cat_count['count']."";
}

Comment: this gives me correct number but how to push this number to final result - $result it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **AS** alias to get count in a variable and then use it in your next query.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from cat_count");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```

Then use it as:

```
$result=mysql_query ("SELECT title, image FROM board order by date limit ".$data['total']);cq();
```

Comment: welcome @AliBaba glad to help. Have a good day!